# How to mock useHistory hook in jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am using UseHistory hook in react router v5.1.2 with typescript? When running unit test, I have got issue.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined.

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import {Action} from 'history';
import * as router from 'react-router';
import { QuestionContainer } from './QuestionsContainer';

describe('My questions container', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        const historyHistory= {
            replace: jest.fn(),
            length: 0,
            location: { 
                pathname: '',
                search: '',
                state: '',
                hash: ''
            },
            action: 'REPLACE' as Action,
            push: jest.fn(),
            go: jest.fn(),
            goBack: jest.fn(),
            goForward: jest.fn(),
            block: jest.fn(),
            listen: jest.fn(),
            createHref: jest.fn()
        };//fake object 
        jest.spyOn(router, 'useHistory').mockImplementation(() =>historyHistory);// try to mock hook
    });

    test('should match with snapshot', () => {
        const tree = mount(<QuestionContainer />);

        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Also i have tried use `jest.mock('react-router', () =>({ useHistory: jest.fn() }));` but it still does not work.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I needed the same when shallowing a react functional component that uses `useHistory`.

Solved with the following mock in my test file:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: jest.fn(),
  }),
}));
```

Comment: For those who use TypeScript, this approach may cause the "React.createElement: type is invalid — expected a string" error if the component uses `Link` and `useHistory` at the same time. Erhan's approach won't cause that issue.

Comment: Is there a way to capture `useHistory().push()` invocations?

Comment: But how do you spyOn useHistory function?

Comment: Those who are using TypeScript may refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62774929/10959940  :)

Comment: @proustibat, can you provide a bit elaborated example ? Also, update the example with .test.js file

Comment: @taystack you may want to check the answer I posted for this question ^_^

Comment: @omeralper you may want to check the answer I posted for this question ^_^

Comment: @targumon I solved this by scoping the jest.fn() outside the mock. It can be referenced easily this way. Mocking the router has been abstracted into a helper method already.

Answer (score 55):

This one worked for me:

```js
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: jest.fn()
  })
}));
```

Comment: this approach preserves the other react-router-dom functions which you may not want to mock

Comment: @Erhan i have done the same. but again it is throwing error :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined. any suggestion ?

Comment: This won't work in TypeScript, as it will give the following error: `TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.`

Comment: For TypeScript support, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62775608).

Answer (score 33):

Wearing my politician hat I'll dare to state that you're asking the wrong question.

It's not `useHistory` that you want to mock. Instead you'd just want to feed it with history object which you control.

This also allows you to check for `push` invocations, just like the 2 top answers (as of writing this).

If that's indeed the case, `createMemoryHistory` got your back:

```
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history'

test('QuestionContainer should handle navigation', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory()
  const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(history, 'push') // or 'replace', 'goBack', etc.
  render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <QuestionContainer/>
      </Router>
  )
  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button')) // or whatever action relevant to your UI
  expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: I tried this one, my onClick is working ( checked by console logging) but history.push is not being fired , can you help to debug it

Comment: @RanjanKumar hard to debug without seeing code... but I'll try anyway: are you spying on 'push' like in my example and yet the toHaveBeenCalled expectation fails?

Comment: I think you're right to wear that hat. I didn't really want to mock history. I wanted the error I got when calling `useHistory` to go away! Rendering inside `<Router history={createMemoryHistory()}>` did the trick nicely for me!

Answer (score 29):

Here's a more verbose example, taken from working test code (since I had difficulty implementing the code above):

**Component.js**

```
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
  ...

  const Component = () => {
      ...
      const history = useHistory();
      ...
      return (
          <>
              <a className="selector" onClick={() => history.push('/whatever')}>Click me</a>
              ...
          </>
      )
  });
```

**Component.test.js**

```
  import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
  import { act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
  import { mount } from 'enzyme';
  import Component from './Component';
  it('...', () => {
    const historyMock = { push: jest.fn(), location: {}, listen: jest.fn() };
    ...
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Router history={historyMock}>
        <Component isLoading={false} />
      </Router>,
    ).find('.selector').at(1);

    const { onClick } = wrapper.props();
    act(() => {
      onClick();
    });

    expect(historyMock.push.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual('/whatever');
  });
```

Comment: it worked for me. I had to use this trick with typescript though: <Router history={historyMock as unknown as RouterProps["history"]}>

Answer (score 20):

In the Github react-router repo I found that the `useHistory` hook uses a singleton context, and that you can use a `MemoryRouter` to provide that context in tests.

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
const tree =  mount(
    <MemoryRouter>
        // Add the element using history here.
    </MemoryRouter>
);
```

Comment: Please let us know how we will get *...props* value ??

Answer (score 7):

A way to mock the push function of useHistory:

```
import reactRouterDom from 'react-router-dom';
jest.mock('react-router-dom');

const pushMock = jest.fn();
reactRouterDom.useHistory = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({push: pushMock});
```

Then, how to check if the function have been called:

```
expect(pushMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(pushMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something');
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, I was having problems with useLocation too

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: jest.fn()
  }),
  useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    pathname: '/another-route',
    search: '',
    hash: '',
    state: null,
    key: '5nvxpbdafa'
})}))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the above answers very helpful. However I missed the ability to spy and actually test functionality. But simply naming the mock function first solved that for me.

```
const mockPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useHistory: () => {
    const push = () => mockPush ();
    return { push };
  },
}));
```

Comment: Why so cumbersome? This should be written like this:
`useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockPush
  })`