# Enzyme & React router: How to shallow render a component with useHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, enzyme

What I've been trying is to render a component with `shallow`, which is provided by `enzyme`.

The component is using `useHistory` from `react-router-dom`.

```
const baseMatch: match<{ id: string }> = { /* path, url, params */};
const location = createLocation(baseMatch.url);

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const baseProps = {
    history: createMemoryHistory(),
    location: createLocation(baseMatch.url),
    match: baseMatch
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      useHistory: jest.fn()
    }));
  });

  afterEach(() => { jest.clearAllMocks() });

  it('renders blah blah', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...baseProps} />);
    // testing MyComponent here...
  });
```

I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392815/how-to-mock-usehistory-hook-in-jest), and put `jest.mock` in the same way.

However, this results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`.

The console says:

```
MyComponent › renders blah blah

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

      24 | const MyComponent = (props: IProps) => {
      25 |   console.log('useHistory', useHistory);
    > 26 |   let history = useHistory();
```

Strangely, the `console.log` in line 25 above prints the implementation of `useHistory` (In other words, it's not undefined).

Clearly, `useHistory` isn't mocked.
I suspect that `useHistory` can't be mocked with `shallow` (In the post above, the poster was using `mount()`).

However, I'm not 100% sure because I can't find if `shallow` is compatible with `useHistory` or not from the docs of `enzyme` and `react-router`.

Is it possible to use `shallow` with `useHistory`? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks):

> Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs jest.mock('moduleName') to
>   be in the same scope as the require/import statement.

So instead of mocking react-router-dom in `beforeEach` - try having it at the top scope:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useHistory: jest.fn()
}));

const baseMatch: match<{ id: string }> = { /* path, url, params */};
const location = createLocation(baseMatch.url);


describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const baseProps = {
    history: createMemoryHistory(),
    location: createLocation(baseMatch.url),
    match: baseMatch
  };

...
```