# jest mock axios doesn't provide proper mock for axios

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I'm trying to provide a mock request for this class and then expect that `history.push` is called with some path.

**Start.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ReactComponent as Arrow } from '../../arrow.svg';


export default function Start() {
    let history = useHistory();
    const doInitializeApp = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/asap/start')
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data == true) {
                    history.push('/login')
                } else {
                    alert('something went wrong. Could not start the application')
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                alert('something went wrong. Could not contact the server!')
            });
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">

                <div className="content">
                    <div id="box">
                        <h1>Welcome</h1>
                        <Arrow id="next" onClick={doInitializeApp} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And this is my approach for the test

**Start.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Start from '../components/startscreen/Start';
import { ReactComponent as Arrow } from '../arrow.svg';
import axios from "axios";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
describe('Start', () => {
    it('test axios get reroute the application to path /login', () => {
        const mProps = { history: { push: jest.fn() } };
        const wrapper = shallow(<Start {...mProps} />);
        const arrow = wrapper.find(Arrow);
        const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');

        //mock axios
        jest.mock("axios");
        //mock axios response
        axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: true });
        //simulate onclick
        arrow.simulate('click');
          
        expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); --> this pass
        expect(mProps.history.push).toBeCalledWith('/login'); --> this doesn't pass
    })
});
```

However, the test did not pass because the actual `axios.get(url)` doesn't take the response which I mocked and it always come to the `.catch(err => ...  "Could not contact the server!")`

What did I do wrong in here ? Because that the code didn't come to the `if (res.data===true)` so that I also couldn't test whether the `history.push` is actually called or not.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553208/enzyme-react-router-how-to-shallow-render-a-component-with-usehistory) answer your question?

Comment: actually not. I did not even pass the code line `if (data ===true)` in my test object, because the mock axios reponse did not work. It always come to the `catch (err =>` code line instead

Comment: Can you update the question with your latest code and share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) reproducing the issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-brown-v26jn this is the code i wanted to test. However in the App.test the test won't work... But the App.js is the class I want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Your mocking code is fine. The code in the `catch` block is getting executed since `useHistory()` returns `undefined` (You can confirm this by `console.log`ging the error inside the `catch` block).

One way to fix it would be to mock `useHistory` and pass a mock function for `history.push`. You can then spy on `useHistory()` to confirm the `history.push` got called with `/login`.

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
// other import statements omitted for brevity

jest.mock('axios')

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
  const fakeHistory = {
    push: jest.fn()
  }

  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useHistory: () => fakeHistory
  }
})

const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate)

describe('Start component', () => {
  test('redirects to /login', async () => {
    const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(useHistory(), 'push')
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: true })

    const wrapper = shallow(<App />)
    const button = wrapper.find(Arrow)
    button.simulate('click')
    await flushPromises()
    expect(pushSpy).toBeCalledWith('/login')
  })
})
```

I'm using `setImmediate` to wait for the async action to complete as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045733/3724716).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but I'm getting error at line  `const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(useHistory(), 'push')` saying useHistory() is not defined

Comment: @Betoobb Looks like you're not importing `useHistory` in the test. The test should pass when you do.

Comment: I still get this problem. ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` at the line `const doInitializeApp = () =>{axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/asap/start')}.then(...)` . It seems like the mocked axios response is not recognized. This problem also happend before. Maybe it cause because of the way i write the function?