# Mocking useHistory and expect toBeCalledWith

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I wan't to check if `history.push()` has been called with the correct parameters in my test. 
I'm not sure what's the correct way to mock `useHistory()`

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58581010/3247934) solution. But it seems that I can't check if `push()` has been called.

App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const onClick = () => {
        history.push('/anotherPath');
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={onClick}>click</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

App.test.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import {render, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    useHistory: () => ({
        push: jest.fn(),
    }),
}));

test('renders learn react link', async () => {
    const app = render(<App/>);
    fireEvent.click(app.getByText('click'));
    expect(useHistory().push).toBeCalledWith('/anotherPath');
});
```

Is there any way to make sure that `history.push()` has been called with the correct parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assign the mocked `push` method into a variable and use that to assert if it is called with the right parameters.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const onClick = () => {
    history.push("/anotherPath");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockHistoryPush
  })
}));

test("renders learn react link", async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  fireEvent.click(getByText("click"));
  expect(mockHistoryPush).toBeCalledWith("/anotherPath");
});
```

Comment: cannot access mockHistoryPush inside jest.mock

Comment: this has no sense, `expected(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith("/anotherPath");`

Comment: @pmiranda you need to store `jest.fn()` into a variable, since calling it creates a new function. 

Follow exactly what I did.