# Mocking react-router-dom for useHistory hook causes the following error - TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jestjs, react-hooks

I am trying to mock `react-router-dom` in one of my test cases so that the `useHistory` hook will function in my tests. I decide to use `jest.mock` to mock the entire module, and `jest.requireActual` to preserve  the other properties that I may not want to mock.

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  useHistory: () => ({
    location: {
      pathname: '/list',
    },
  }),
}));
```

This is actually derived from one of the highly rated solutions to the following question: [How to mock useHistory hook in jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392815/how-to-mock-usehistory-hook-in-jest)

However, the TypeScript compiler is flagging the following error on the following line `...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),`

> TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.

Interestingly, I only face this issue after updating jest and ts-jest to the latest versions (jest v26). I do not face any of these issues when I was using jest 24.x.x.

```
"@types/jest": "^26.0.4",
"jest": "^26.1.0",
"ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue for the latest jest versions?

Comment: What is being returned from `jest.requireActual('react-router-dom')` ?

Comment: Supposedly the other properties/methods from 'react-router-dom' package? The point of me doing the above is to only mock the `useHistory` hook, rather than the entire package.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`jest.requireActual` returns `unknown` type that cannot be spread.

A correct type is:

```
import * as ReactRouterDom from 'react-router-dom';

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as typeof ReactRouterDom,
  useHistory: ...,
}));
```

A quick fix is `any`:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any,
  useHistory: ...,
}));
```

It's acceptable because it doesn't impair type safety in this case.

Since `react-router-dom` is ES module, a more correct way to mock it is:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any,
  __esModule: true,
  useHistory: ...,
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my issue. Any idea why would this error only appear on the jest 26?

Comment: Another point to add, for those who are using the default recommended eslint settings, you will need to add `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion` above the `ReactRouterDom` type assertion, despite eslint telling us that there is no need to assert the type.

Comment: Probably you used older TS version that don't have this behaviour, or used another Jest setup with different typings, there's also third-party `@types/jest`. That's true, I always disable this rule by default.

Comment: `requireActual` [is generic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9c680c4/types/jest/index.d.ts#L184-L189), so an alternative is: `...jest.requireActual<typeof ReactRouterDom>("react-router-dom")`.

Comment: I can confirm that the solution from @JonathanReyes works just as well :)

Comment: Hi @wentjun, the disable the eslint doesn't seem to work on my code of 

`
jest.mock('../../theme/device', () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion
  return {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion
    ...jest.requireActual('../../theme/device'),
    useMediaQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false),
  };
});
`

Comment: @AnnieHuang What exactly doesn't work? There is no type assertion (`as any`) in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this when using it for `typescript` instead of `react-router-dom`, what worked for me is:

```js
import ts from 'typescript';

jest.mock('typescript', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('typescript') as Record<string, unknown>,
  nodeModuleNameResolver: ...,
}));
```