# How can i access the history object inside of this promise call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

In the React component, A button submission takes the values of text fields on the page and passes them into mockFetch. Then, If the promise of mockFetch is successful, It causes a `history.push('/newaccount')` to fire.

I set up my test to click on the button and then attempt to detect the `history.push('/newaccount')` call with what i passed into it, but my mock history.push doesn't get called. Does anyone know what i can do to get this test to pass?

EDIT: It turns out replacing the current jest.mock with:

```
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const pushSpy = await jest.spyOn(history, "push");
```

allows me to call the mocked history when the `history.push` is OUTSIDE of the mockFetch function... but not when it is inside of it. That's what i'm trying to figure out now.

Main app routing:

```
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Banner />
      <div id="mainSection" className={classes.root}>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Paper>
            <Router history={history}>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/newaccount">
                  <NewAccountPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/disqualify">
                  <DisqualificationPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                  <LandingPage />
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </Paper>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Component: (omitted some redundant fields)

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextFieldStyled from "../TextFieldStyled/TextFieldStyled.js";
import * as actionTypes from "../../redux/actions/rootActions.js";
import {
  checkAllErrors,
} from "../../validators/validators.js";
import mockFetch from "../../fetchCall/fetchCall";
import "./LandingPage.css";

const LandingPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const {
    changeCarPrice,
    changeErrorMessage,
    resetState,
  } = actionTypes;

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch({ type: resetState });
    };
  }, [dispatch, resetState]);

  const { carPrice } = useSelector(
    (state) => state
  );

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!checkAllErrors(allErrors)) {
      // Call the API
      mockFetch(carPrice)
        .then((response) => {
          history.push("/newaccount");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          dispatch({ type: changeErrorMessage, payload: error });
          history.push("/disqualify");
        });
    }
  };

  const [allErrors, setAllErrors] = useState({
    carValueError: false,
  });

  return (
    <div id="landingPage">
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={2} />
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container id="internalLandingPageForm" spacing={4}>
              {/* Text Fields */}
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextFieldStyled
                  info={"Enter Car Price ($):"}
                  value={carPrice}
                  adornment={"$"}
                  type="number"
                  label="required"
                  required
                  error={allErrors.carValueError}
                  id="carPriceField"
                  helperText={
                    allErrors.carValueError &&
                    "Please enter a value below 1,000,000 dollars"
                  }
                  passbackFunction={(e) => handleChange(e, changeCarPrice)}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container id="internalLandingPageFormButton" spacing={4}>
              <Grid item xs={4} />
              <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  type="submit"
                  id="applyNowButton"
                  title="applyNowButton"
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                >
                  Apply Now
                </Button>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={5} />
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} />
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Test:

```
const wrapWithRedux = (component) => {
  return <Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>;
};

  it("simulates a successful submission form process", () => {
    const mockHistoryPush = jest.fn();
    jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
      useHistory: () => ({
        push: mockHistoryPush,
      }),
    }));

    render(
      wrapWithRedux(
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/newaccount">
              <NewAccountPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <LandingPage />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      )
    );

    const carPriceField= screen.getByTestId("carPriceField");
    fireEvent.change(carPriceField, { target: { value: "5000" } });

    const buttonSubmission= screen.getByTitle("buttonSubmission");
    fireEvent.click(buttonSubmission);


    expect(mockHistoryPush).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/newaccount');
  });
```

Comment: Can you add a `console.log` statement inside the `if (!checkAllErrors(allErrors)) {...}` block to make sure it does call `mockFetch`?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Just added it inside of the .then of the mockFetch and it does get called. So the code does get to the history.push("/newaccount")

Comment: Cool. I'm guessing the expectation runs before the promise returned by the `mockFetch` function resolves. You could test this by commenting out the `mockFetch` call and adding  a `history.push` inside the `if` condition. And if you could add a CodeSandbox URL with your code, it would be easier to debug.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan Hm if i move the history.push out of the mockFetch call i still get the same error of the ```jest.fn()``` never being called. I'm beginning to think it's how the ```history.push``` is mocked.

Comment: I have made some progress on this.

If i do:
```    
const history = createMemoryHistory();
const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(history, "push");
```

then i can access the mocked history.push outside of mockFetch. But if it's inside the promise function mockFetch... i cannot. I presume this has something to do with it being in a promise.

Comment: You mean it didn't work when the only thing the `handleSubmit` function did was `history.push`?

Comment: > then i can access the mocked history.push outside of mockFetch. But if it's inside the promise function mockFetch... i cannot. 

Not sure if I understand. You only need to add `expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/newaccount')` right?

Comment: It worked when i moved the ```history.push``` outside of the ```mockFetch``` function. It did not work when i left the history.push INSIDE of the mockFetch function.

To get it to work inside the mockFetch function, i had to add await waitFor wrapped around my expect line.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. As I mentioned earlier, your expectation does not wait for the async action to complete.

Answer (score 0):

so after looking further into mocking history, i found this from [How to mock useHistory hook in jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392815/how-to-mock-usehistory-hook-in-jest)

The answer seems to be to do the code below and then the pushSpy will be called

```
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(history, "push");

    render(
      wrapWithRedux(
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/newaccount">
              <NewAccountPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <LandingPage />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      )
    );
```

I also had to wrap the expect line using `waitFor` from the react testing library to get the `history.push` to call the mock inside of the `mockFetch` function like so:

`await waitFor(() => expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/newaccount"));`

With these two modifications, the test now passes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mock a bunch of things and test implementation, I would test the behavior.

Here are some ideas to maybe help writing for behavior over implementation details.

**Refer to React Router testing docs**

React Router has a [guide on testing navigation](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing/navigating) based on actions.

**Hijack `render()` to wrap with Redux**

Rather than writing a Redux wrapper for every test suite, you could hijack the `react-testing-library`'s `render()` function to get a clean state or seed the state. Redux [has docs here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components).

**Don't mock `fetch()`**

> A button submission takes the values of text fields on the page and passes them into mockFetch

I would use an HTTP interceptor to stub a response. That way you get the async behavior and you bind your tests to the backend vs binding it to the tool. Say you don't like `fetch()`, you'll be stuck with it until you migrate everything. I made a blog post on the subject [Testing components that make API calls](https://www.anthonygonzales.dev/blog/how-to-test-data-fetching-components.html).

Here's your code example with some edits:

```
  it("creates a new account", () => { // <-- more descriptive behavior
    // Stub the server response
    nock(`${yoursite}`)
      .post('/account/new') // <-- or whatever your backend is
      .reply(200);

    render(
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/"]}> // <-- Start where your forms are at
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/newaccount">
              <NewAccountPage />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <LandingPage />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </MemoryRouter>
    );

    const carPriceField= screen.getByTestId("carPriceField");
    fireEvent.change(carPriceField, { target: { value: "5000" } });

    const buttonSubmission= screen.getByTitle("buttonSubmission");
    fireEvent.click(buttonSubmission);


    expect(document.body.textContent).toBe('New Account Page'); // <-- Tests route change
  });
```