# Jest mock function not being called

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

My component code is as below. Not an expert in Jest mocking. referred [How to mock useHistory hook in jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392815/how-to-mock-usehistory-hook-in-jest) and mocked useHistory.push. But the mock function is not being hit. I would appreciate any suggestions

```
const ReviseAction = ({
  plans,
  template,
  coveragePercentage,
  territoryName,
  existingTemplateId,
}) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleRevise = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: "/xxx",
      state: {
        plans: plans,
        template: template,
        coveragePercentage: coveragePercentage,
        territoryName: territoryName,
        existingTemplateId: existingTemplateId,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <button
      data-testid="revise-button"
      onClick={handleRevise}
      key="revise-button"
    >
      Revise
    </button>
  );
};
```

Here is my test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import ReviseAction from "./ReviseAction";
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

describe("ReviseAction", () => {

    jest.mock("react-router-dom");

    const pushMock = jest.fn();
    //reactRouterDom.useHistory = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({push: pushMock});

    jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
        ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
            useHistory: () => ({
                push: jest.fn()
            })
        }));

    it("Renders component", async () => {
        render(
            <Router>
                <ReviseAction 
                    plans={[]}
                    template={{}}
                    coveragePercentage={"12"}
                    territoryName={"Name"}
                    existingTemplateId={"1234"}
                />
            </Router>
        );

        fireEvent.click(screen.queryByTestId("revise-button"));
        expect(pushMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

and getting

> ```
> Expected number of calls: >= 1
> Received number of calls:    0
> ```

Comment: Mocking `useHistory` is not recommended anymore. Instead, we should use `<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}/>` or `createMemoryHistory`, see https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it.
What I did:
Changed HashRouter import to router
passed the mock history as props to router.

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import ReviseAction from "./ReviseAction";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";

describe("ReviseAction", () => {

    const mockPush = jest.fn();
    jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
        useHistory: () => ({
            push: mockPush,
        }),
    }));
    const mockHistory = { push: mockPush, location: {}, listen: jest.fn() };
    it("Renders component", async () => {
        render(
            <Router history={mockHistory}>
                <ReviseAction 
                    plans={[]}
                    template={{}}
                    coveragePercentage={"12"}
                    territoryName={"Name"}
                    existingTemplateId={"1234"}
                />
            </Router>
        );

        fireEvent.click(screen.queryByTestId("revise-button"));
        expect(mockPush).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```